# Get PlaceHolder Text and Replace it in file - Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to write a function in **Ruby** that gets a template **File** that contains **PlaceHolders** and replaces it with another value, in the next form:

template File example:

```
server {
  server: {{SERVER_NAME}}:{{SERVER_PORT}}
  server_name {{APP_HOST}};
  listen *:80 default_server;
  server_tokens off;
  root /dev/null;    
}
```

So I want to find all PlaceHolders and the content inside.
In this example I want to get:

> "SERVER_NAME" , "SERVER_PORT" and "APP_HOST"

Because I got variables with those names that contain the value I want to seed.

I don't know how many PlaceHolders exist in a given template file (suppose to be generic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
(?<=\{\{)([^{]+?)(?=\}\})
```

By that you get your desired values. You may use your own approach to replace them.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KYag6P/1/)

[Ruby Demo](http://ideone.com/125t8b)